# python won't handle characters

Tags: python, json, character

I'm writing a code that searches a .json with data about all the Magic the Gathering cards according to many possible different criteria.

It works fine except that whenever a card has characters such as "-" in its text, my code will ignore that text entirely. It is as its text field was blank.

At some point in the code, the cards' texts are appended to a list, and maybe that's where the problem lies, because i made a simple .py file to test something different, and i can get the text.

```
for i in data:
    if data[i]["name"].find(" some name*  ")!=-1:
        print data[i]["text"]
```

This is working actually. it prints the text of the card flawlessly.

however, when i switch this to

```
for i in data:
    if data[i]["name"].find("   some name*   ")!=-1:
        somelist.append(data[i]["text"]
print somelist
```

i will find the same issue again. i will get the text of cards that don't have characters such as "-" on them.

EDIT: This is an example of text that python will ignore:

```
"+3: Destroy target noncreature permanent.\nâˆ’2: Gain control of target creature.\nâˆ’9: Nicol Bolas, Planeswalker deals 7 damage to target player. That player discards seven cards, then sacrifices seven permanents."
```

This â^'9 should be translated to "-".

Another text example that has been ignored every single time is this:

```
"Target creature gets -1/-1 until end of turn.\nMorbid â€” That creature gets -13/-13 until end of turn instead if a creature died this turn."
```

Comment: could you show exactly which text is not appended?  As you sure the bad character is ASCII `-` and not a Unicode character?

Comment: You should provide working code and a minimal data set that shows the behavior.